# Making an image gallery, how?

Tags: php, mysql, limit, image-gallery

[image]

This is the idea of what I want to do. Let the user upload an image and display it in the gallery. The gallery shows the first 8 thumbs, with 2 rows of 4, and when you click on it the users sees the image in a fancybox. But how can I get the right 8 images from my database? I know you can `SELECT * FROM table limit number,number` But I don't know how to calculate those numbers with PHP. Can someone help me set up my gallery?

Comment: Do I understand your question correct: You only want to show the images by the uploader?

Comment: "Wanna" is not a word, please stop using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have information about the current page the user is on like as a GET parameter "p".
Now you can simply use that to find your missing numbers. The first one would be p*8 and the second one p*8+8. Those would be the pictures you want to display on the current page.

Comment: Soo, if $amount=8, is the first one $_GET['p']*$amount and the second one first+$amount?

Comment: I haven't used php since version 4 but I think you'll have to use a function to convert the string GET["p"] to a integer. Then you can use it as you described.